# How do I get overall Facebook page video view counts by month?

Tags: facebook, facebook-insights

We are having a lot of success pushing video onto Facebook and driving video views and engagement. But I am having trouble finding anything about how to retrieve this info either through the Insights tools or via the API.

There is [this post](https://www.facebook.com/business/news/Coming-Soon-Video-Metrics) from back in May of last year that points to video metrics, but I can't find it live anywhere.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/insights#page_video_posts

Comment: Well, yes and no. It appears right now the issue is the ?period qualifier doesn't seem to work for videos. It seems to only want to return lifetime results which makes my job of computing "monthly" stats really difficult.

Comment: It's not that other period values don't work. The table shows that 'lifetime' is the only period value that video requests will take. So, it looks like you would need to store the values locally to compute monthly metrics.

Comment: That's pretty annoying to allow only LIFETIME period. I am having the same problem - trying to display the daily stats on the graph but looks like it's not possible then?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook finally launched this feature a couple weeks ago. The url for this is

https://www.facebook.com/[your-page-name]/insights?section=navVideos